# How To Clear Androids LRUCache

Tags: android, android-lru-cache

In the API of Google Developer there is a trimToSize() Method, that I can't find / use.
How do I clear or reduze the size of my LRU Cache ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public final void evictAll ()
```

Added in API level 12

Clear the cache, calling `entryRemoved(boolean, K, V, V)` on each removed entry.

Use this method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you also know how I can remove the halfe of all older objects. I mean clear the cache to the halfe with older objects ?

Comment: Try calling  public final V remove (K key) method so that you can remove a particular entry. Try to call this based on the entry count

Comment: But I do not know the keys.

Comment: how you are inserting items to LRUCache?

Comment: chaotics. depends on the users behaviour and I do not maintain a seperate list of keys. :-(

Comment: If you not how you can remove it. Just keep a list of keys if you want to get it removed.

Comment: I guess i'll have to do that. Thanks !

Comment: use evictAll() method to remove all the elements

Comment: `snapshot()` might be of value to anyone looking at this. It returns an LRU ordered list of keys in cache.

Comment: @j2abro Thank you, I will update the answer and would be helpful for others.